# G4L and the CLEANHP option

Tags: disk-image

Yesterday I used G4L (Ghost For Linux) to image my Ubuntu 18.04.3LTS with no problem, but trying to image my Windows Visa 64 keeps giving me this error:
"lzop: short write: File too large" after about 4-5% completion when it stops and gives me the error...

I've used G4L on my Vista64 before - twice - with no problem, but I keep getting some version of "...File too large" error even if I use the GZIP or BZIP2 compression option as well. Tried different kernels too...

I noticed the option "CleanHP: clear Hiberfil.sys and Pagefile.sys before NTFSCLONE" - question, could it be that my hibernation (or pagefile) file is the problem and I need to run this 'tool' before imaging? Don't remember having to do that in the past... and if I do use the 'cleanhp' will it crash out my Vista64?

Comment: Still not sure of what the G4L tool "CleanHP: clear Hiberfil.sys and Pagefile.sys before NTFSCLONE" is used for... but would not solve my problem anyway since issue was FAT32 related.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can't use G4L to image to a USB drive formatted to **FAT32**... apparently the dang thumb drive I got yesterday was formatted FAT32 and I forgot to check before wasting HOURS trying to write my VISTA64 image on it. That's why the File too large error - too large for FAT32...

...so, REFORMATTED the USB drive to NTFS, and the backup using G4L is working fine...

*Found Clue HERE: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/backup-error-lzop-file-too-large-stdout.19315/